# javascript dynamic link based on input with shortened values?

Tags: javascript

Ok, so I am trying to have a simple javascript or php or anything that will allow me to copy and paste a full 16 digit number into a field but then just uses the first 6 digits and adds them on the end of a url.

This is what I have so far...

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>BIN Search</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('#button').click(function(e) {
                var inputvalue = $("#input").val();
                window.location.replace(" https://bincheck.org/" + inputvalue);

            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <input class="form-control" id="bin" type="number" placeholder="Enter card" autofocus="">
    <button type="button" id="button">Search</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery `val()` function returns a string representing the content of an input element (the input element `el` exposes this as `el.value`).

There are a lot of operations that are available for a string instance. What you want to do is to take a subsection of the string, or `substring` for short. See some documentation regarding the [substring method at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring).

In your case you want to change your callback to something along this line:

```
function(e) {
    var inputvalue = $("#input").val();
    window.location.replace("https://bincheck.org/" + inputvalue.substring(0, 6));
}
```

Comment: It's definitely closer than what I had, but it just seems to open a dialogue box with the url I need to have the page direct to...  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Note that `$("#input")` is invalid - an input has another ID - `bin`. You can use substring to chunk the input:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

            $('#button').click(function(e) {
                var inputvalue = $("#bin").val().substring(0, 6);
                // console.log(" https://bincheck.org/" + inputvalue);
                window.location.replace(" https://bincheck.org/" + inputvalue);
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="form-control" id="bin" type="number" placeholder="Enter card" autofocus="">
<button type="button" id="button">Search</button>
```

Comment: Instead of a dialogue box with the url, is there a way to get the url to just load in the browser?

Comment: `window.location.replace(" https://bincheck.org/456456");` replaces the current document with a new one, so in general, does what you expect. Dialog box may be displayed when you have unsubmitted changes in the form or so. Can you share an example on a separate page like with jsbin to illustrate the problem? This code works fine if I run it in a separate window

Answer (score 0):

> /** Changes in your code as per your requirement: **/

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>BIN Search</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {

                $('#button').click(function(e) {
                    var inputvalue = $.trim($("#bin").val());
                    if(inputvalue.length == 16){
                           window.location.replace(" https://bincheck.org/" + inputvalue.substring(0,6));
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input class="form-control" id="bin" type="number" placeholder="Enter card" autofocus="">
        <button type="button" id="button">Search</button>
    </body>
</html>
```